# How to covert a dictionary to a particular form string, with double quotes " replaced by \"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a dictionary like this -

```
{'type': 2,
 'minutely': {},
 'hourly': {},
 'daily': {'atHour': '17', 'atMinute': '0'},
 'weekly': {'weekdays': []},
 'monthly': {'weekdays': []},
 'advancedCronExpression': ''}
```

I've done json.dumps to covert this dictionary into a string.

```
test_string = json.dumps(test_dict)
test_string
O/P: '{"type": 2, "minutely": {}, "hourly": {}, "daily": {"atHour": "17", "atMinute": "0"}, "weekly": {"weekdays": []}, "monthly": {"weekdays": []}, "advancedCronExpression": ""}'
```

I've to covert it into a target string like this; this is necessary because the api needs it in this form only -

```
target string -
"{\"type\":2,\"minutely\":{},\"hourly\":{},\"daily\":{\"atHour\":\"17\",\"atMinute\":\"0\"},\"weekly\":{\"weekdays\":[]},\"monthly\":{\"weekdays\":[]},\"advancedCronExpression\":\"\"}"
```

I've tried like -

```
test_string.replace('"','\\"')
'{\\"type\\": 2, \\"minutely\\": {}, \\"hourly\\": {}, \\"daily\\": {\\"atHour\\": \\"17\\", \\"atMinute\\": \\"0\\"}, \\"weekly\\": {\\"weekdays\\": []}, \\"monthly\\": {\\"weekdays\\": []}, \\"advancedCronExpression\\": \\"\\"}'
```

I'm not sure whether I'm approaching this in the right way or not. I've to dynamically update the parameters keeping the same string format. I've tried with Python Regex also. Any suggestion?

Comment: `json.dumps()` it a 2nd time?

Comment: After converting the dict to string, I've used replace. One time json.dumps()

Comment: The point is that if you `json.dumps()` it a second time, you'll get those backslashes.

Comment: You're seeing the `repr` of your string. Do `print(test_string.replace('"','\\"'))` to see the actual string

Answer (score 1):

```
inp = {'type': 2,
  'minutely': {},
  'hourly': {},
  'daily': {'atHour': '17', 'atMinute': '0'},
  'weekly': {'weekdays': []},
  'monthly': {'weekdays': []},
  'advancedCronExpression': ''}

target = r'''"{\"type\":2,\"minutely\":{},\"hourly\":{},\"daily\":{\"atHour\":\"17\",\"atMinute\":\"0\"},\"weekly\":{\"weekdays\":[]},\"monthly\":{\"weekdays\":[]},\"advancedCronExpression\":\"\"}"'''

target == json.dumps(json.dumps(inp, separators=(',',':')))
# True
```

You need to be super careful about how things get printed when you're comparing. This is the difference between `__repr__` and `__str__`. `__str__` gets used for `print()` but just displaying to terminal uses `__repr__`

Example:

```
x = """{"a":1}"""
print(x)
# {"a":1}

x
# '{"a":1}'

x2 = json.dumps(x)
print(x2)
# "{\"a\":1}"

x2
# '"{\\"a\\":1}"'
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
import json

test_dict = {
    'type': 2,
    'minutely': {},
    'hourly': {},
    'daily': {'atHour': '17', 'atMinute': '0'},
    'weekly': {'weekdays': []},
    'monthly': {'weekdays': []},
    'advancedCronExpression': ''
}

test_string = json.dumps(test_dict)
test_string = test_string.replace('"', '\\"')
print(test_string)

with(open('result.txt', "w")) as result:
    result.write(test_string)
```

for me this returns targeted string
[image: results]

The thing is that you probably check the `test_string` value in debugger, where `"//"` is displayed. Printing the variable on the console, or saving it in file gives you the target string.

Comment: This works as a one-off, but it's not reliable -- some strings require more escaping than just quotes. For example, if the "real" string contains a tab, the first JSON encoding will change it to `r'\t'`, and the second one needs to change it to `r'\\t'`.